# How to link to all class constants in JavaDoc

Tags: constants, javadoc

I frequently feel like I want to reference @see Class#{all_constants} , in JavaDoc.  Is there any way to do that ?   For example, what if i want to provide a reference to the possible values for a bitflag ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I haven't found a standard way to do this. You can certainly create a relative HREF, as follows:

```
<a href="../../constant-values.html#my.package.MyClass">MyClass constants</a>

<a href="../../../../constant-values.html#my.deeply.nested.package.MyClass">MyClass constants</a>
```

The trouble is, this isn't safe to use when refactoring. The relative path must be adjusted for the number of symbols in the package name, and the fully-qualified class name must be part of the anchor. It's very error-prone and not likely to be supported by any IDE. I'd be delighted to find out that there's a better answer, but this is all I have right now.